# Color Picker for OS X

Tags: macos, color

Is there any app for mac which I use to know the RBG value of the point where my mouse is right now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely. Check out the *DigitalColor Meter* tool in your *Utilities* folder. It does exactly what you want.